# Is law enforcement aware of the Continental?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-2

Both John Wick and John Wick Chapter 2 have scenes where a cop shows up in the house of Wick and seems to ignore what happened there. From there, it is possible to establish at least that particular cop knows John Wick and knows of the Continental infrastructure.

However, in the Chapter 2 movie there are several scenes of mercs attacking Wick in the middle of street with several witnesses, and there is no sign of any law enforcement.

In the end of Chapter 2, Winston made it clear that the Continental is powerful enough to fill up a whole park of people.

Are law enforcement agencies aware of the existence of the Continental or even a part of it? Is the lack of police just a detail that no one seemed to care in the movie?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cop scene explanation from John Wick (2014)](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68085/cop-scene-explanation-from-john-wick-2014)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, the police are most likely aware of the Continental. They simply turn a blind eye as long as no cops or innocent people are killed.**

<sub>[Shamelessly copied from my own answer to a similar question.](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/78117/48480)</sub>

John Wick's directors Chad Stahelski and Dave Leitch discussed interactions between the police and the assassins [during an interview with Screen Junkies](https://youtu.be/3DNQJE8eHjw). (Creators of Honest Trailers)

> **Screen Junkies**: I've always been curious about [the cop scene]. Is he an assassin inside the police force? Is that just a friend of
>   [John's] who is on the inside?
>
> **Chad Stahelski**: If you notice, in either of the John Wick movies; ***they don't kill innocents, they don't kill cops, it's completely
>   hidden within their own business. So as long as they maintain that,
>   the cops are cool.*** [...] There aren't any dirty cops. It's just,
>   ***they're in the know, we're in the know, it's good***. The cops have their
>   own world [which] we want to keep separate.
>
> **Dave Leitch**: Yeah, [the cops] have their own underworld as well, and he would be part of that.
>
> **Chad Stahelski**: Jimmy would be part of it, but there is a mutual respect there.
>   <sub>[-HONEST REACTIONS: John Wick Directors React to The Honest Trailer! (16:15)](https://youtu.be/3DNQJE8eHjw?t=964)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Law enforcement is aware of them, but it would seem they look the other way. The movie doesn't explain(nor does it need to) where law enforcement is, and why they don't go after these assassins.

In the second movie, it seems even some residents of New York look the other way, as established in the subway scene. It looks like as long as you stay out of the assassins way, and don't have a contract on you, then you're safe.

A [link](https://filmschoolrejects.com/38-things-we-learned-from-the-john-wick-commentary-b077c6dfa2b6/#.kshu59tcg) explaining that the world of John Wick is like a comic book world, and a different reality.