# Why does the public show no reaction to killings in John Wick 3?

Tags: realism, john-wick-chapter-3-parabellum

The entire movie felt like there's been a bit of a disconnect from the surrounding world every time John Wick was fighting. So what really bothered me were a few scenes where he is slashing foes in public while everyone around seems to be just walking by showing zero emotion or concern almost as if they don't see it for some reason. Was it shown that way intentionally or is there some surrealistic portrayal that I didn't understand?

Comment: related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68085/cop-scene-explanation-from-john-wick-2014 https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73694/why-is-everybody-there-in-the-park-at-the-end-of-john-wick-chapter-2

Comment: In the world of John Wick, people are used to incidents like these, while they being ordinary to them, they probably know better than mix up themselves with crazy assassins, they have their own lives to live safely

Comment: isn't this the same explanation for https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73694/why-is-everybody-there-in-the-park-at-the-end-of-john-wick-chapter-2  ?